# Drawing Circles to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jframe

I'm having issues drawing some circles to my JFrame. I originally had it using the default layout and realized this was only adding the most recent circle, so I changed the layout to null, and now nothing gets drawn. I've also tried `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout())` which also doesn't draw anything. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 * @author Christopher Nielson
 *
 */
public class Main {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static Random rand;
    private static Jiggler jiggler;
    private static ArrayList<JComponent> circles;
    private static int fps;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);

        rand = new Random();
        circles = new ArrayList<JComponent>();

        int x = frame.getWidth();
        int y = frame.getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i++) {
            circles.add(new Circle(rand.nextInt(frame.getWidth()), rand.nextInt(frame.getHeight()), 
                    rand.nextInt(frame.getWidth() / 10) + 100, rand.nextInt(frame.getHeight() / 10) + 100, null));
        }

        circles.forEach(current -> {
            frame.add(current);
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);

        jiggler = new Jiggler(circles, new JLabel("FPS: "));    // TODO add fps
        jiggler.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And this is one reason you'll see us recommending time and time again to avoid using null layouts like the plague.

Having said that, your main problem is a design problem, not a layout problem, and that problem being that your Circle class **shouldn't extend JComponent** or any component for that matter, since if you want to draw multiple circles, you should have only one component, probably a JPanel doing the drawing, and the Circles should be logical classes, classes that have a `public void draw(Graphics g)` method, not component classes. You would pass the List of Circles to your drawing JPanel, and it would draw the Circles in its paintComponent method by calling the `draw(g)` methods of each Circle in the list.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawChit extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 900;
    private static final int PREF_H = 700;
    private static final int MAX_SHAPES = 30;
    private List<MyShape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public DrawChit() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SHAPES; i++) {
            double x = (PREF_W - 100) * Math.random();
            double y = (PREF_H - 100) * Math.random();
            double w = 100 + (Math.random() * PREF_W) / 10;
            double h = 100 + (Math.random() * PREF_H) / 10;
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);

            float hue = (float) Math.random();
            double delta = 0.3;
            float saturation = (float) (Math.random() * delta + (1 - delta));
            float brightness = (float) (Math.random() * delta + (1 - delta));
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, brightness);
            shapes.add(new MyShape(ellipse, color));
        }

        // we'll throw a black square in the middle!
        int rectW = 200;
        int rectX = (PREF_W - rectW) / 2;
        int rectY = (PREF_H - rectW) / 2;
        shapes.add(new MyShape(new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, rectW, rectW), Color.BLACK));

        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // use anti-aliasing to make graphics smooth
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // iterate through the shapes list, filling all 
        for (MyShape shape : shapes) {
            shape.fill(g2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point p0 = null;
        private MyShape shape = null;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }

            // iterate *backwards* so get top-most Shape
            for (int i = shapes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (shapes.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    p0 = e.getPoint();
                    shape = shapes.get(i);

                    // move selected shape to the top!
                    shapes.remove(shape);
                    shapes.add(shape);

                    repaint();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p0 != null) {
                moveShape(e.getPoint());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p0 != null) {
                moveShape(e.getPoint());
                p0 = null;
                shape = null;
            }
        }

        // translates the shape 
        private void moveShape(Point p1) {
            int deltaX = p1.x - p0.x;
            int deltaY = p1.y - p0.y;
            shape.translate(deltaX, deltaY);
            p0 = p1;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        DrawChit mainPanel = new DrawChit();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Chit");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class MyShape {
    private Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
    private Color color;

    public MyShape(Shape shape, Color color) {
        path.append(shape, true);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return path.contains(p);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.draw(path);
    }

    public void fill(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fill(path);
    }

    public void translate(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        path.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(deltaX, deltaY));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is for an assignment, and it was specified that the Circle class extend JComponent. It has a paintComponent method in it. They did get drawn, the issue isn't with the circle, since one would show up with the default GridLayout; it was working properly. BUT, I need more than one circle, which is why I tried both FlowLayout and null layout...and they don't show up with those layouts.

Comment: I suppose I should mention I have to be able to drag the circles (which I have yet to implement), which I suppose is why they extend JComponent.

Comment: @Kofu: that requirement -- to be able to drag circles, yes means that a JComponent or JPanel must be extended, but only **one** must be extended. You must rig this single JPanel to be able to draw and drag multiple circles, and there's the crux, and the reason that there can only be one, **if you want the circles to potentially overlap**.

Comment: @Kofu: so if Circle must extend JComponent, and you want to draw multiple circles that are draggable, then you must rig this class to draw those multiple circles. That is why you'll still likely need a non-component logical class that the drawing component holds multiple copies of.

Comment: @Kofu: for example please see my answer and code to a similar question: [drawing shape objects in java (draggable,resizable and can rotate)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22595225/522444)

Comment: I see your point. Could you answer my original question though? Why do the circles not show up at all after I changed the layout, when it did originally?

Comment: @Kofu: null layouts require that you be responsible for complete control over component size and position. If you add a component to a null-layout using container and don't specify these properties, the component will not show, since it will default to a size of [0, 0].

Comment: @Kofu: for example